# Measurability of one set of measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ be a standard Borel spaces (a Borel subset of a complete separable metric space), and let $\mathcal B(X),\mathcal P(X)$ denote collection of Borel sets and Borel probability measures on $X$ respectively, the latter being endowed with a topology of weak convergence.
Consider a set $J\subseteq X\times \mathcal P(Y)$ such that section $J_x\neq\emptyset$ for any $x\in X$ and suppose that $J$ is an analytic set.

For a product measure $P\in \mathcal P(X\times Y)$ by $P_X$ we denote its marginal on $X$, and by $\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dP_X}$ the corresponding conditional distribution (stochastic kernel on $Y$ given $X$). Let's say that $P$ is $J$-feasible whenever
$$
  P_X\left(x\in X:\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dP_X}(x)\in J_x\right) = 1.
$$
Can I show that the set of all $J$-feasible measures is analytic? I believe, the solution can be found if the answer to [that question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160658/existence-of-a-conditional-distribution) is affirmative.

Comment: what does it mean "$J$ is analytic"?

Comment: @user126154: here are some definitions of [analytic sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set). You can think of it as a set obtained as a continuous image (e.g. a projection) of a Borel set. It is not necessarily Borel, but it belongs to a completion of a Borel $\sigma$-algebra w.r.t. any Borel probability measure.

Comment: Disclaimer: as my previous comment demonstrates, I'm not an expert of the field. Now, any measure $P\in\mathcal P(X\times T)$ disintegrates as a family of measures $\mu_x\in\mathcal P(Y)$, which is measurable w.r.t. the extremal $P_X$. Forgetting the extremal, this gives you a map $F:\mathcal P(X\times Y)$ to $X\times \mathcal P(Y)$. I read in the wikipage that analityc sets are closed under (continuous) preimages. So a set is $J$-feasible if it is exactly $F^{-1}(J)$ hence it should be analytic whenever $J$ is.

Comment: @user126154: Thanks, I am actually working on the idea of representing the set of $J$-feasible measures as a pre-image of $J$. However, I am not sure whether you method works: if $F$ is a disintegration operator, its codomain is not $X\times \mathcal P(Y)$, rather it is a subset of $\mathcal P(Y)^X$

Comment: I see. You can go from $\mathcal P(Y)^X$ to $X\times \mathcal P(Y)$ using the graphic function $G$: given a function $x\to\mu_x$ consider the set $\{(x,\mu_x): x\in X\}\subset X\times \mathcal P(Y)$. Now the composition $G\circ F:\mathcal P(X\times Y)$ goes to the set of subsets of $X\times \mathcal P(Y)$ and the set of $J$-feasible is $\{P$ such that $G(F(P))\subset J\}$ which is not exactly the pre-image of $J$. Is it true that if $J$ is anlytic then the set $\{A$ such that $A\subset J\}$ is analytic as a subset of the set of subsets?

Comment: @user126154: I don't think there is a natural topology on the powerset, or that the powerset is Borel space in this topology. Anyway, I wouldn't expect your set to be analytic. I think the proof is easier and connects to [this question of mine](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160658/existence-of-a-conditional-distribution).